# How to implement reliable smooth scroll for hash links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement smooth scrolling on my site when clicking anchor links (links with a hash, `#something`).

The problem is that I can't figure out how to implement it without *something* not working properly.

**Current solution**

I have several pages representing weeks with headers for each weekday, (`#1`, `#2`, ...) and links to them (`#1-marker`, `#1-marker`, ...). Since they don't match, the built-in browser scrolling is disabled. I then use the following script to make them work both on load and on link clicks:

```
$(function()
{
    // Handle anchor reference links
    $('a[href*=#]')
        .click(onAnchorClick);

    // Smooth school to hash on load if any in URL
    if(location.hash)
        $(location.hash+'-marker')
            .smoothScroll();
});


function onAnchorClick(event)
{
    // Scroll to 0 if hash is #top
    if(this.hash == '#top')
    {
        scrollTo(0);
        return false;
    }
    // Try smooth scroll. Return true for default behavior if hash
    // isn't on the current page
    return $(this.hash+'-marker').smoothScroll() ? false : true;
}


$.fn.smoothScroll = function()
{
    // If we have any elements to work on
    if(this.exists())
    {
        // Scroll to top of the target
        scrollTo(this.offset().top);
        return this;
    }
    return false;
}


$.fn.exists = function()
{
    // Used to check if a selector got any elements back
    return this.length > 0 ? this : false;
}


function scrollTo(target)
{
    // Animate scrollTop
    $('html,body')
        .animate({scrollTop: target}, 500);
}
```

When clicking on a link it checks if the target hash exists on the current page. If it does, it scrolls to it, if it doesn't the link works as usual and switches page.

**Problem**

Thought it worked great, but then I discovered a glitch: I have a global link for quick access to the current week and day. The problem is that since all week pages have the same links, the quick access link matches even on other weeks. So if I am on week 40 and the current week is 50 and I click on Thursday, it goes to Thursday in week 40 instead of week 50.

I have tried to fix it using href matching agains document urls to disable the functionality when the link doesn't target the current page and similar workarounds, but no matter what I do, something seems to break.

Have any of you implemented this successfully? How do you do this reliably and have all links work properly?

---

**Some example HTML**

The URLs are actually `year/quarter/week#day`.

```
  <!-- Quick access to current day in current week -->
  <aside id="go-today">
    <a href="2014/1/13#1" title="Go to Today">Today</a>
  </aside>

  <!-- Regular list on a page which can be to any week-->
<ul class="listing days">
    <li><a href="2014/1/13#1">Søndag</li>
    <li><a href="2014/1/13#2">Mandag</li>
    <li><a href="2014/1/13#3">Tirsdag</li>
    <li><a href="2014/1/13#4">Onsdag</li>
    <li><a href="2014/1/13#5">Torsdag</li>
    <li><a href="2014/1/13#6">Fredag</li>
    <li><a href="2014/1/13#7">Lørdag</li>
</ul>


  <!-- Toolbar for quick access to days in week being viewed -->
<div id="toolbar">
  <a href="2014/1/13#1" title="Søndag">Sø</a>
  <a href="2014/1/13#2" title="Mandag">Ma</a>
  <a href="2014/1/13#3" title="Tirsdag">Ti</a>
  <a href="2014/1/13#4" title="Onsdag">On</a>
  <a href="2014/1/13#5" title="Torsdag">To</a>
  <a href="2014/1/13#6" title="Fredag">Fr</a>
  <a href="2014/1/13#7" title="Lørdag">Lø</a>
  <a href="2014/1/13#top" title="Topp">
    <img src="_/up-arrow.svg" class="icon"/>
  </a>
</div>

  <!-- Example of a target marker id -->
  <article class="day">
      <h2>
          <span class="marker" id="2-marker"/>
          <a href="2014/1/13#2">Mandag</a>
      </h2>
```

Comment: can you demo some html?

Comment: This is an example of a day? `<article class="day"></article>`???

Comment: the way you're doing it needs to be adjusted. Can you add a class `current` to today's element and this week's element or do you not have that type of ability?

Comment: I have complete control, so yeah, I ended up changing the colliding URLs completely so that the problem isn't a problem anymore even though its still a problem, hehe. So it works now, but issue still exists, so still curious if there is a reliable way to do this. If anyone knows, please share :)